# Exception in AWS lambda function is empty

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I'm trying to serialize an exception in an AWS lambda function, but when I do it, the object has no properties. Here is a simplified version of this:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  try {
    var x = some.property;
    context.succeed(null);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("error=" + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    context.fail(err);
  }
};
```

Here's the log output. Note that when I `JSON.stringify` the exception object, there's nothing there, but in the `context.fail` line, the exception data is there.

```
START RequestId: 810913d1-567b-11e5-a0d1-95dad6b9184b
2015-09-08T22:46:55.308Z    810913d1-567b-11e5-a0d1-95dad6b9184b    error={}
2015-09-08T22:46:55.368Z    810913d1-567b-11e5-a0d1-95dad6b9184b    {"errorMessage":"some is not defined","errorType":"ReferenceError","stackTrace":["exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:5:17)"]}
END RequestId: 810913d1-567b-11e5-a0d1-95dad6b9184b
REPORT RequestId: 810913d1-567b-11e5-a0d1-95dad6b9184b  Duration: 174.72 ms Billed Duration: 200 ms     Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 9 MB
```

Anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: Create custom output handler and that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties of the Exception might have been defined with `Object.defineProperty`. if you run the following example, you'll see that they don't get serialized

```
function Exception () {
    this.message = function () {
        return 'Oh NOES';
    };
}

Exception.prototype.constructor = Exception;

Object.defineProperty(Exception.prototype, 'foo', {
    get: function () {
        return this.message();
    }
});

var e = new Exception();

console.log(e.foo) // 'Oh NOES'
console.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, 2)); // {}
```

Comment: Good thought, but `console.log(err.errorMessage)` returns `undefined`. :(

Comment: Interesting, what do the following things output with `console.log`: `err.constructor`, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(err)`, `Object.keys(err)` ?

Comment: `err.constructor=function ReferenceError() { [native code] }`, 
`getOwnPropertyNames=stack,arguments,type,message`. So then I tried each of those 4 properties and they have their own values. So it looks like `context.fail` must take the native properties and then construct its own JSON for output. I don't know why I can't see those when I stringify the object, but at least I can figure out to get the data I need. Thanks!